# git clone over HTTPs timeout

Tags: git, https, timeout, clone, cocoapods

I'm using git clone over HTTPs

```
git clone https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS.git
```

and get this

> Failed connect to github.com:443; Operation timed out

The problem is it fails 9 of out 10 times. VERY UNPREDICTABLE. I updated to use `homebrew git version 2.0.1` and openssl seems up to date

> OpenSSL 0.9.8za 5 Jun 2014 built on: Aug 10 2014 platform:
>   darwin64-x86_64-llvm

I have these in my .gitconfig file

```
[credential]
    helper = osxkeychain
[http]
    sslVerify = false
    postBuffer = 524288000
[https]
    sslVerify = false
    postBuffer = 524288000
```

But the problem still exists. This leads to problem like this [Attempt to read non existent folder](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2649)

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you at work behind a proxy? Have you tried running the same command on an alternate connection, say your home or friend's Broadband/Cable internet or your mobile phone tethered?

I've had a lot similar issues and a corporate proxy was usually the main culprit. I say this because when something so widely used and available as github is involved it's most likely something on your side and not github.